# Error with CocoaPods dependencies (Multiple Podfiles were found) while setting up react react native CLI environment on MacOS M1

Tags: react-native, terminal, npx

After I create a new project using the below code in terminal

```
niteshrastogi@Niteshs-MacBook-Air ~ % npx react-native init AwesomeProject1
```

Takes a lot of time on Installing Cocoapods dependencies step and returns an error. [See this Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4j10.png)

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✔ Installing Bundler
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/niteshrastogi/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:129:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/niteshrastogi/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:181:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/niteshrastogi/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
```

I am new to development and trying to setup a development environment for the first time. Any help with this would be helpful.

Followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to set up react native CLI and create my first project.

System config: M1 Ventura 13.2 macos watchman version: 2023.02.06.00 homebrew version: Homebrew 3.6.21 node: v19.6.0

Also installed Xcode with the latest version and selected the latest command line tool location.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvmM1.png)